# How I can set a temporary title on batch script?

Tags: batch-file

Is there a way to set a title in a batch script that will desappear when the program exits?

In my case, I want to set 'JCC' as a title, but using `title JCC`, the title will remain when the program exits.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no chance to do that in pure batch scripting, you'll have to do that using a tool that is capable of GUI window manipulation...

Comment: One work-around is to simply set the title back to "Command Prompt" after the program exits, but that doesn't work if there was a non-default title there to begin with.  By "program exits" what exactly are you referring to anyway?  It would really help if you could post an [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was searching and I found a solution:

```
@echo off
if "%~1" equ ":SET-TITLE" goto %1
cmd /c "%~f0" :SET-TITLE %*
pause
exit /b

:SET-TITLE
shift /1
title JCC
```

This will work. It's recommended to delete the fourth line to make it usable and leave the SET-TITLE paragraph at the bottom of the file. Also remember that you must put an exit /b before the SET-TITLE paragraph.

Comment: This is a nice work-around using a new `cmd.exe` instance for executing the script! Though I don't get why you recommend to delete the fifth line (which is `exit /B`) and at the same time you say there must be `exit /B`…

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, you are true! Now it's fixed.